# Why are the characters in xterm so small and how do I change it?

Tags: xterm

[image: So small!!!!]

Why are the characters in xterm so small and how do I change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no configuration defined for `xterm`. Create a configuration:

```
nano ~/.Xresources
```

and add these lines

```
xterm*faceName: Ubuntu Mono:style=Regular:antialias=true
xterm*faceSize: 12
XTerm*Background: black
XTerm*Foreground: grey
```

and run this command:

```
xrdb -I$HOME ~/.Xresources
```

<sub>[Read more](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_resources#Xterm_resources)</sub>

Comment: Ok, that worked, but now the background is white. How do I change it back to black?

Comment: `XTerm*Background: black` and `XTerm*Foreground: grey`

Comment: And? does it work?

Comment: It somehow fixed itself...

Comment: Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me an upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers ;)

Comment: Now I can finally use xterm too!  **;-)**